# general affine transform - matrix and offset - how to get offset

Tags: image-processing, graphics, transform, linear-algebra, affinetransform

An affine transform has two parts to it:
A matrix and an offset.

I have a matrix set up like this:

[x' y' 1] = M * [x y z].

I can successfully estimate M by multiplying the left by the right side of the matrix, but this will not give me the offset parameters. How can I arrange the setup so I access offset parameters, as well?

Comment: If your matrix is `M` and your offset `v` (a vector), you have to multiply `M` by `[x y z]` and then sum `v` this way: `M*[x y z] + v`.

Comment: One correspondence is not enough to uniquely define all degrees of freedom (6 for 2D, 12 for 3D). What do you actually want to do?